# Django tag based on model and view not showing on webpage

Tags: django, python-3.x, macos, postgresql

I am trying to show another table with postgresql data on my django webpage. The page does show the normal HTML content, but it is not showing the postgresql data.

Interestingly, the Django shell does indicate the data is available:

```
In [1]: Companystats.objects.all()
Out[1]: <QuerySet [<Companystats: Companystats object (AAPL)>, etc
```

I tried:

1. restarting the server (python3 manage.py runserver)
2. python3 manage.py makemigrations
3. python3 manage.py migrate

Simplified code:

**HTML webpage**

```
{% for compstat in compstats %}
{{ compstat.symbol }}
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Companystats(models.Model):
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    symbol = models.TextField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'companystats'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Companystats

def companystats_list(request):
    compstats = Companystats.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'compstats': compstats})
```

any ideas on what i could try to fix it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you log `compstats` before `render` are there data?

Comment: thanks for your response. i did a quick look-up on stackexchange, could you explain how to do that?

Comment: check length of rendered list , print (len(compstats )) before return in views

Comment: print(compstats) before return. See it contains data or not.

Comment: Having `models.TextField` as a  `primary_key` is not generally a good idea. Try to print `{{ compstats|length }}` before the for cycle in the template to see if there is acually any compstat.

Comment: thanks for the comments! i'm starting to see how django can be debugged by using. 1. log to file 2. log to runserver window 3. to html output. Regarding the {{ compstats|length }} it outputs 0. So no data though.

Comment: Thanks to the debugging comments i was able to figure out that the class Companystats(models.Model): was never loaded. So i moved compstats code to the News(models.Model). Now i can see the output from compstats on the webpage output. However i am wondering why my second view Companystats(models.Model) is not loaded by Django, anyone?

Comment: Do you have the app your `models.py` are nested in in `INSTALLED_APPS`? If not, that's the reason, because Django finds models and creates/applies migrations for them. Then add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and `makemigrations` then `migrate`.

Comment: appreciate your comment. I have the following in my settings.py. The blog refers to the app: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]